# Distance between a point and a line in space with unknown line equation

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d, plane-geometry, fixed-points

We have $A(-2,3,1)$ and we have to find the distance from $A$ to line which contains point $P(-3,5,2)$ and this line makes equal points with coordinate axis.
I know how to solve this, I need the equation of that line, and for that I need a point, which is $P$ and a paralel vector to that line, but I don't know how to find that vector.

Comment: This is a 3D problem. A line doesn't have an equation.

Comment: What does "makes equal points with coordinate axis" mean?